# Border spacing not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

So some reason I cannot get my border spacing to work. No matter what size I set it to nothing happens. I'm only using the border for a top line.

My CSS

```
p {
    border-spacing: 5000px;
    text-align: right;
    color: silver;
    font-size: 70%;
    border-style: solid;
    border-top: solid silver;
    border-width: thin;
    border-bottom: none;
    border-right: none;
    border-left: none;
}
```

MY HTML

```
<p>COPYRIGHT © ERNST EVERYTHING INC. ALL RIGHTS RESERVED</p>
```

Answer (score 4):

`border-spacing` only applies to tables. Try using this for your CSS:

```
p {
    text-align: right;
    color: silver;
    font-size: 70%;
    border-top: thin solid silver;
    padding-top: 5000px;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

border-spacing is only available for tables, not paragraphs. use padding instead.

```
p {
 text-align: right;
 color: #C0C0C0;
 font-size: 70%;
 border-top: 1px solid #C0C0C0;
 padding-top: 5000px;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, looks like I beat you by three seconds XD

Answer (score 1):

`border-spacing` is a property of tables, not block objects like you're using.

Answer (score 0):

Because it's style for `<table>` tag. Try this:

```
<style>
   table {
    border: 4px double #333; 
    border-collapse: separate; 
    width: 100%;
    border-spacing: 7px 11px;
   }
   td {
    padding: 5px; 
    border: 1px solid #a52a2a;
   }
  </style>


 <table>
   <tr>
    <td>1</td><td>2</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>3</td><td>4</td>
   </tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! How do I remove the left, right and bottom table/lines?

Comment: try: table { border-top: 1px solid #000; border-left: 0;border-right: 0; border-bottom: 0; }

Comment: <style>
   table {
    border: 4px single #333; 
    border-collapse: separate; 
    width: 100%;
    border-left-width: 0px;
   }
   td {
    padding: 5px; 
    border: 1px solid #a52a2a;
   }
  </style>This does nothing to the left boarder